# Twitter Bootstrap: icons in button dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, offset

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DjHyQ/) is the link on jsfiddle with some demo. It works well in Chrome and even in IE, but in FF icons get down. How can I fix it without moving them up with negative margins or something like this? I have no ideas why this happens.

[image: FF]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following style

```
.dropdown-menu a {
    white-space:normal;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DjHyQ/47/).

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! But why there is white-space:nowrap; definition in bootstrap.css, and why stripping of whitespace has such impcat?