# Adding icons to a Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, icons

I want to add some icons to links in a Bootstrap dropdown, using code like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i><a href="#">Up</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i><a href="#">Down</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i><a href="#">Left</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i><a href="#">Right</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, the icons are out of place:

[image: dropdown issue]

I tried using the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694866/twitter-bootstrap-icons-in-button-dropdown/11695326?noredirect=1#comment22712019_11695326), but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody provide a solution and explain why/how it works?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywkLt/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Put the icons inside the anchor tags:

```html
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Some Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i> Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i> Down</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i> Left</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> Right</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Twitter bootstrap specifically used the i tag as it is an inline element. That way, you can use it inside <p> and <a> tags and it's still semantically correct. This is the method I'd use for sure.

Comment: @N1ck, but why doesn't it work this way(firefox): http://jsfiddle.net/ywkLt/40/ ? Any clues how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @BradBarrow it may be syntactically correct, but I don't think using i for icons is semantically accurate :)

Comment: I recommend adding the following css to your site so that icons are aligned roughly the same. If you have masking and layering it won't work as well.
`.dropdown-item i {
    min-width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}`

Answer (score 13):

Used to **Position**

**Define your** `.dropdown-menu li` `position relative` **and** i define `position absolute`

as like this

```
.dropdown-menu a {
    white-space:normal;
}
.dropdown-menu > li{position:relative;}

.dropdown-menu > li > i{position:absolute;left:0;top:3px;}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ywkLt/2/)**

Comment: With this method, clicking the icon won't have the same effect as clicking the links.

Comment: @N1ck, some of us may want that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Put the icons inside the anchor tags for Bootstrap v3 (with icons from http://www.FontAwesome.com):

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">A Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Down</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Left</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> Right</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9ce3P/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="pull-right">Edit</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-left"></span>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="pull-right">Delete</span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-left"></span>
            <span class="clearfix"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```